# How to get sum of all matches of HLOOKUP in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

Suppose I write
HLOOKUP('apple', A1:E10, 2, FALSE)

Then HLOOKUP will return 100 because it finds the first match.
But, as you can see in the attached picture, apple is preset in two columns. The corresponding values in row 2 are 100 and 70. I want that the sum of the two values i.e. 170 should be returned.

In this example, the lookup value is present in columns A and C. But it can be present in any columns and it can be present in any number of columns. I want that the formula should find all and sum the corresponding values in the 2nd row. How can I achieve that?
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:E1="apple")*(A2:E2))
```

[image]

To include more columns than just **A** through **E**, use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((1:1="apple")*(2:2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=SUMIF(A1:E1,"apple",A2:E2)
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:E1="apple")*A2:E2)
```

**Results:**

[image]